# Karma-Jasmine: How to test ionicModal in a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

**THE SITUATION:**

I am unit testing my Angular / Ionic app.

I am testing the lockscreen and having troubles with the modal.

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
```

I already read some solutions for controllers, but i have not seen any solution for factories yet.

**THE CODE:**

**The factory:**

```
.factory('Service', function ($ionicModal) {
    var obj = {};

    var setup;

    /**
     * Sets the lockscreen code.
     */
    obj.setCode = function (code1, code2) {
        if (code1 == code2) {
            window.localStorage["code"] = code1;
            setup.hide();
        } 
    };
    /**
     * Opens the lockscreen setup.
     */
     obj.showSetup = function () {
   if (window.localStorage["code"] == undefined) {
      $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('.../xy.html')
          .then(function (modal) {
                setup = modal;
                setup.backdropClickToClose = false;
                setup.hardwareBackButtonClose = false;
                setup.show();
                        });
                }
       };
});
```

**The test:**

```
describe('Testing Lockscreen', function(){
  var Service;

  beforeEach(module('starter'));

    var fct = null;
    beforeEach(inject(function(Service) {
      fct = Service;
    }))

 it('on success', function(){

     spyOn(fct, 'setCode').and.callThrough()

     fct.setCode('1234','1234');
     expect(window.localStorage["code"]).toBe('1234');
    })
});
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i solve this problem?

Thank you very much!